# I want a widget to appear on only one page

Tags: editor, code, widget-text

I have a rotating images widget I want to display on my homepage. My selected homepage is a static front page I created with several other pages to make my blog look more like a website than a blog, and then I have a separate blog page. The widget does not come with shortcode. Rather it comes with something like code that I have to insert in editor in a place that will make the widget appear where I want the rotating images to appear. What I've figured out with trial and error is that when I insert the code into the page.php I can get it to show up exactly where I want it on my selected home page. The problem is that it also shows up on all the other pages except the blog page. So, what I need to do is to write some additional code telling wordpress to only show the widget on the one page. Any ideas on how to write this code?

Here is the code that comes with the widget:

```
<?php include (ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/featured-content-gallery/gallery.php'); ?>
```

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it with the [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) conditional like so:

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { include (ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/featured-content-gallery/gallery.php'); } ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the gallery widget is a standard widget that you can drag and drop into the sidebar, as opposed to needing the php function to call it, try [WordPress › Widget Logic « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/)

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/featured-content-gallery/ does not extend a Widget

Answer (score 0):

You can copy *page.php* to *page-{slug}.php* and add the code there.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

You can try matching against [`get_the_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) or `$post->ID` directly. Using an `if ... else` clause.

```
if ( get_the_ID() == 12 )
    include (ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/featured-content-gallery/gallery.php');
```

This is not a Widget in the WordPress sense, by the way.